# Unexpected result of `predict_function` (Empty batch_outputs)

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

[image]

### After running this entire code, I am receiving the errors :

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1068/2789069822.py in 
----> 1 y_pred = (lstm.predict(x_test) > 0.5).astype("int32")

c:\users\anubhab\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
71         finally:
72             del filtered_tb

c:\users\anubhab\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
2373                         )
2374             if batch_outputs is None:
-> 2375                 raise ValueError(
2376                     "Unexpected result of `predict_function` "
2377                     "(Empty batch_outputs). Please use "

ValueError: Unexpected result of `predict_function` (Empty batch_outputs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.

I tried different methodologies as lstm_predict() isn't present in tensorflow 2.5, so I tried to change the command, but it didn't come into effect